Difference between `initializeMint` and `initializeMint2`
When initializing the mint accounts, two methods may be used ìnitializeMint and initializeMint2.
What are the differences between the two?

The only difference is that initializeMint required that you pass in the rent sysvar account to when invoking the instruction while in initializeMint2 this isn't a requirement
example using initialize_mint ix
solana_program::program::invoke(
        &spl_token::instruction::initialize_mint(
            &spl_token::ID,
            mint_info.key,
            mint_authority_info.key,
            freeze_authority_info.map(|i| i.key),
            decimals,
        )?,
        &[
            token_program.clone(),
            mint_info.clone(),
            mint_authority_info.clone(),
            rent_sysvar.clone(), // needed in the `initialize_mint` ix
        ],
    )

accounts passed into initializeMint -> https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L793
accounts passed into initializeMint2 -> https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L822
Functionality there is no difference between the two instructions as initializeMint2 uses the initializeMint processor method, ref: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5380b0e7e2f4a479a450c1b7091690ddb312ba73/token/program/src/processor.rs#L76
